# Where does the problem or bug lie in the logic of this while loop Machine Learning Cubic Root-Finding algorithmic code that calls a function?

Tags: python, function, loops, debugging, logic

**Goal:** The goal of this program is to find additional accelerators to the convergence process of cubic or n-polynomial root finding methods/algorithms.

**Problem:** The code can not tabulate one variable from the upper section of while loops for some unknown reason I can't delineate. Variable **"tbl_val_6"** is not defined despite it being clearly defined above (in the code) in the sixth loop. (See sixth line in **"Tabulation"** code...)

**Tabulation:**

```
z = [('Halley (Lower)','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_1**(10**9),iter_num_1),
    ('Halley (Upper)','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_2*(10**9),iter_num_3),
    ('Bisection','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_3*(10**9),iter_num_3),
    ('Regula Falsi','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_4*(10**9),iter_num_4),
    ('Secant','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_5*(10**9),iter_num_5),
    ('Halley (Lower)', 'Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_6*(10**9),iter_num_6),
    ('Halley (Upper)','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_7*(10**9),iter_num_7),
    ('Bisection','Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_8*(10**9),iter_num_8),
    ('Regula Falsi','Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_9*(10**9),iter_num_9),
    ('Secant','Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_10*(10**9),iter_num_10),
    ('Halley (Lower)', 'Version 3', act_rad,tbl_val_11*(10**9),iter_num_11),
    ('Halley (Upper)','Version 3', act_rad,tbl_val_12*(10**9),iter_num_12),
    ('Bisection','Version 3',act_rad,tbl_val_13*(10**9),iter_num_13),
    ('Regula Falsi','Version 3',act_rad,tbl_val_14*(10**9),iter_num_14),
    ('Secant','Version 3',act_rad,tbl_val_15*(10**9),iter_num_15),]

tbl = tabulate(z, headers=['Numerical Method','Version','Act. Val' 'Approx. Val','#Iterations'], 
tablefmt='fancy_grid')
print(tbl)
print("***Where Version 2: Iterative Root and Version 3: Reciprocal Factorial: Convergence 
Accelerators")
```

**Associated Error:**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-657a5a0a1bbf> in <module>
    460     ('Regula Falsi','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_4*(10**9),iter_num_4),
    461     ('Secant','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_5*(10**9),iter_num_5),
--> 462     ('Halley (Lower)', 'Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_6*(10**9),iter_num_6),
    463     ('Halley (Upper)','Original',act_rad,tbl_val_7*(10**9),iter_num_7),
    464     ('Bisection','Version 2',act_rad,tbl_val_8*(10**9),iter_num_8),

NameError: name 'tbl_val_6' is not defined
```

This is the sixth loop out of fifteen that computes the iteration and approximate cubic root. It can not define **"tbl_val_6"** because the variable defining it **"x_new_low_H_2"** can not be defining meaning it is most likely having issues calling the functions outside of its loop structure. Or I think it is, however, why did the others have no issue?:

**Sixth Loop (where "tbl_val_6" id defined) and it and all 15's initial conditions:**

***Ini.Cond.***

```
#Root-Finding Method Initial Conditions
crit_lim_low = 1000
crit_lim_up = 1000
itr = 0
```

***Sixth Loop (out of 15):***

```
# Halley's (Lower)

while crit_lim_low > .0005:
    x_new_low_H_2 = guess_low - ((2*f(guess_low)*df(guess_low))/((2*(df(guess_low))**2)- 
    (f(guess_low)*ddf(guess_low))))
    crit_lim_low = abs(act_rad - x_new_low_H_2)
    if crit_lim_low <= .0005:
        itr += 1
        iter_num_6 = itr #iter number for table
        itr = 0 #Re-initializion
        crit_lim_low = 1000
        tbl_val_6 = x_new_low_H_2 #value of approx. root (table)
        guess_low = act_rad - 10 
        break
    elif itr >= 1000:
        print("Lower Guess Halley's Method Failed(V.2): Check parameters.")
        itr = 0
        crit_lim_low = 1000
        guess_low = act_rad - 10 
        break
    else: 
        itr += 1
        j = x_new_low_H_2**(1/itr)
        guess_low = x_new_low_H_2 + j
```

Functions f(x), df(x), and ddf(x) are functions defined above and OUTSIDE of the loop structure; initial conditions and constraints shown for reproducibility:

**Input/Initial Conditions/Functions:**

```
print('User Assumptions/Limitations:')
print('\n')
print('1. Radial Upper Limit must be no more than 100 nanometers')
print('and Radial Lower Limit must be no less than 1 nanometer.')
print('2. Period of diffusion must not exceed 24 hours.')
print('3. Diffusion Rate should be reasonable a number of radial')
print('units (nm) per hour as to not supersede other constraints.***')
print('\n')
print('***Note: r = (dr/dt)t must be between RUL and RLL only!')
print('\n')
ul_rad = (10**(-9))*float(input('What is the radial upper limit (nm)? '))
ll_rad = (10**(-9))*float(input('What is the radial lower limit (nm)? '))
diff_t = (10**(-9))*float(input('What is the period of diffusion (hours)? '))
dr_dt = (10**(-9))*float(input('What is the volume rate of diffusion (nm/hour)? '))
      
#Formula Set-Up

pi = 3.14159265359
import math

#Prelim Calculation

act_rad = math.sqrt((((4/3)*pi*((ul_rad)**3)) - ((4/3)*pi*(dr_dt)*((diff_t)**3)) + ((4/3)*pi* 
((ll_rad)**3)))*(3/(4*pi)))
guess_low = act_rad - 10
guess_up = act_rad + 10
##Functions for Root-Finding Methods
def f(x): #volume
    return(((4/3)*pi*((ul_rad)**3)) - ((4/3)*pi*(x**3)) - ((4/3)*pi*(dr_dt)*((diff_t)**3)) + 
    ((4/3)*pi*((ll_rad)**3)))
def df(x):#surface area
    return((4*pi*((ul_rad)**2)) - (4*pi*(x**2)) - (4*pi*(dr_dt)*((diff_t)**2)) + (4*pi* 
    ((ll_rad)**2)))
def ddf(x):#mean width times curvature
    return(((8*pi*ul_rad) - (8*pi*x) - (8*pi*(dr_dt)*(diff_t)) + (8*pi*ll_rad)))
```

If this needs a **global** function for "**x**" I'm not sure how it would since it should be flagged at the first loop instead of the sixth. Re-initialization of critical values, high and low guesses, and etc. looks fine as well as the **"tabulate"** function. Can anyone see what I am missing? Please be easy on me as I am a novice in Python if the answer is obvious.

**Debugging/Self-Deliberation Notes:**

Yesterday and this morning I tried to make sure my **re-initialization** was fine and triple-checked. I also printed **"tbl_val's"** and **"iter_num's"** from various loops and none of the loops are iterating or the values are too small for the radii, it seems. This may be an overall issue with the **logic** of all **15 separate WHILE loops** and I'm not sure what's going on as I'm taking care to re-initialize. I have a hunch its having issues calling the outside functions but it should've had issues at the start in the **FIRST** loop if that were true.

**Note:** I tried to minimize the code as much as I could but Tabulate, the sixth WHILE loop, and the functions as well as the inputs and initial conditions are KEY and MANDATORY for that output "tbl_val_6". Also, if it is still unclear as to what I am trying to do or more code needs to be seen, I will edit this immediately and as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure of the value of `crit_lim_low` ?

You define `tbl_val_6` in an if clause in a while loop with both the loop and the if clause dependent on the value of `crit_lim_low`.

If `crit_lim_low` is <= 0.0005 then the while loop wont run at all, and you wont define your variable.

Comment: So, you're saying a critical value shouldn't be the defining condition in this and the other 14 root-approximation loops? What would I make the defining condition?

Comment: My logic is so off. I googled a basic while loop logic structure and made a simple loop. I think I figured out my issue. I'll let you know if this works, it should...

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams I don't know enough to say that citical value shouldn't be used, but the reason for that variable giving a NameError is that it isn't being defined and the only way that it can't be defined is if the while loop doesn't run.

Comment: You are right in that it shouldn't be dependent on that value for both. The while loop will terminate when the critical value is met so the if statement is redundant. I ran into more issues down the line...I'm going to post a new question either here or elsewhere about it.